# How to display a custom route on SKmap

Tags: android, skmaps

So if we have a local journey planner, would it be possible to display the route on the Skobbler map?

Is there any method on `SKMapSurfaceView` on Android SDK to pass a route to display it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes - [drawTrackElement](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.1.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#drawTrackElement(com.skobbler.ngx.tracks.SKTrackElement))

You can see an example in the [demo](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) project, the Tracks menu entry.

If you have the route points/list of segments, then you can draw them on the map using a [SkPolyline](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.3.0/index.html) - see the getting started chapter: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec009

Comment: Your answer is pretty unclear. SKtrackElement needs a file. WHile in my case, I have a list of coordinates of each start and end of road segment. Does skobbler have a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I've updated my answer - is the current answer better or are there still questions?