# How to display a route given some points in a database?

Tags: android, skmaps

I have an application that needs to display the path taken.
The coordinates are stored in a database. In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190954/how-to-display-a-custom-route-on-skmap),
it was suggested to use drawTrackElement. That requires the data to come from a file. Is there a way to build the list of points in memory or use the database directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try a polyline: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec009 and see if the result is acceptable to you (if you have enough points in the polyline then the result should be quite smooth).

Comment: It's unfortunate that trackElement does not provide a more flexible way to provide the input points. So, polyline is the only way without resorting to writing to a temporary file.

Comment: For the time being, yes