# Would it be possible to display a custom navigation route on SKmap?

Tags: android, skmaps

According this post [How to display a custom route on SKmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190954/how-to-display-a-custom-route-on-skmap) . 
I try to create new instance of SKtrackElement from list of coordinates. in the demo app the only way to create new SKTrackElement is using SKTracksFile. Is there another way to create new instance of SKtrackElement from list of coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. For the future we're improving the SkPolyline (detailed in the getting started chapter: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec009) to cover this scenario